# How to restrict a user from adding an image in an editable field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I build an online glossary with Node.js and MongoDB.

I have an "Edit" Button which makes a `<dd> </dd>` field editable with `contentediable=true`.

Now the User can write in the field but also can add images via Drag and Drop.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far because I'm a noob in web developing and couldnt find anything related to my issue.

Comment: few pointers: attach event handlers, prevent dragover/drop, prevent copy paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen to `drop` event on `dd` tag and prevent it
using `event.preventDefault()`

```js
var dd = document.querySelector('dd')

dd.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  alert('dropped');
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
dd {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<dd contenteditable="true">asdf</dd>
```

Comment: please avoid codepens or jsfiddles in an answer and post the code here in your answer directly

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

```
let noPictures = document.querySelector(".no-images") // There to select your element
setInterval(() => {
    for (let i of noPictures.children){
    if(i.tagName == 'IMG') {
        noPictures.removeChild(i);
    }
  }
}, 1)
```

(If code founds image, it deletes it)